# How to have more than one ID included in the exclude command?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

```
$product_cats = get_terms('product_cat',array('hide_empty'=>1,'exclude'=>8,'parent'=>0));
```

In the above how do I more add than one id in the exclude field (currently it is 8 and I want to add 9, 10 and 11)?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array to `exclude` parameter:

```
$product_cats = get_terms( 
    'product_cat',
    array(
        'hide_empty'=>1,
        'exclude'=>array(8, 9, 10),
        'parent'=>0
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just another small thing if I make parent => 1 (meaning first sub level), the sub categories are not showing up. Obviously I am doing it wrong!

Comment: `parent` does not take level. It's the parent `term_id`. So you'll have to pass the `term_id` of parent category.